# Install a webserver on OpenSUSE

Tags: terminal, webserver, virtualbox, opensuse

excuse my lack of knowledge but I've just started my apprenticeship.
Is it at all possible to install a webserver on a VM running with OpenSUSE without a GUI, which can communicate with the host and exchange data?

The only solution I've seen so far was to use Apache Webserver but I'm not sure whether I can do that without a GUI...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You don't need GUI to install apache.
OpenSuse uses RMP package management and zypper to install precompiled packages.
Tyr this:

```
su –l

zypper in apache2 apache2-example-pages
```

The su command will give you root privileges and then we use zypper install (in) to add the packages apache2 and apache2-example-pages.

Next, you'll need to start the apache service.

```
rcapache2 start

chkconfig –a apache2
```

Now try to surf to this PC from another PC and see if you get the "It Works" web page.

Answer (score 0):

Simply run this command on your VM to install apache2:

```
# sudo zypper in apache2
```

After installing apache2, you can start it by issuing this command:

```
# sudo systemctl start apache2
```

Use this command if you want to restart apache2:

```
# sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

To stop it, use this:

```
# sudo systemctl stop apache2
```

To make apache2 automatically start on system reboot, use this:

```
# sudo systemctl enable apache2
```

The default document root of apache2 on openSUSE is */srv/www/htdocs/*

Hope this help.